# Can't correctly assign values to a new column, when using boolean indexing (Pandas)

Tags: pandas, boolean

I have a column `Close_open` of Dateframe `df`:

```
Date
2010-02-11    0.00
2010-02-12    0.23
2010-03-19    0.02
2010-04-12    0.05
2010-04-13    0.15
2010-05-07    0.09
2010-05-12    0.03
2010-05-26    0.02
2010-06-18   -0.03
2010-06-22   -0.03
```

I'm trying to create a new column, `Changed` whose value is true when there is a change of sign (going from positive to negative or vice versa) in the  `Close_open` column.

I tried the following code, but I get all falses, when i should be getting at least one true.

```
for i in range(1,10):
        df['Changed'] =abs((df['close_open'][i]) +(df['close_open'][i-1])) < abs(df['close_open'][i])
```

Result =

```
Date           Changed                    
2010-02-11     False  
2010-02-12     False  
2010-03-19     False  
2010-04-12     False  
2010-04-13     False  
2010-05-07     False  
2010-05-12     False  
2010-05-26     False  
2010-06-18     False  
2010-06-22     False
```

However, when I run this code (same code, only not assigning to a df column)

```
for i in range(1,10):
    abs((df['close_open'][i]) +(df['close_open'][i-1])) < abs(df['close_open'][i])
```

I get the following output:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it like this:

```
df['changed'] = df['close_open'] * df['close_open'].shift() < 0

            close_open changed
2010-02-11        0.00   False
2010-02-12        0.23   False
2010-03-19        0.02   False
2010-04-12        0.05   False
2010-04-13        0.15   False
2010-05-07        0.09   False
2010-05-12        0.03   False
2010-05-26        0.02   False
2010-06-18       -0.03    True
2010-06-22       -0.03   False
```

Comment: Thanks. This works as well.  Just for learning purposes is there any way to get this boolean filter working `abs((df['close_open'][i]) +(df['close_open'][i-1])) < abs(df['close_open'][i])` without the for loop I tried to use?  Thank you.

Comment: You just need to add `[i]` on the left hand side:  `df['Changed'][i]`.  What was happening is that the whole column got re-written each time so you were just seeing the results from i = 9 in all rows (if you did range(1,9) it would have been True in all rows).  Note:  not a recommended way to do it, but it would work here and just for learning purposes.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you.